# Vote to close? I disagree, comments?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I saw this on the review queue as a Vote to Close.

[How can I get a me.com e-mail address?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15549/how-can-i-get-a-me-com-e-mail-address)

I voted to leave open - I guess my prerogative as much as anyone else's, but it prompted me to actually Google it afresh & I managed to add a definitive answer to it from Apple's KB.

Now, I'm not looking for a pat on the back;-) but I feel this type of question ought to stay visible, Googleable for future users, as even though it can't be done any more, the info that it can no longer be done would in itself be useful.

I'm never really sure on closed Questions, whether they 'mean less' to future searchers, because they were deemed, for whatever reason 'not worthy of remaining open'. That one in particular already has Protected status.
Should that not give it some leeway on closure?

*tbh, I'm not really sure I'm asking a question, here, or just wanting some high rep/mod input on how this type of 'old news' question should eventually pass down the line into obscurity.*

Answer (score 3):

As you have a good answer with a cite of a reliable source then obviously the question is answerable even if the answer is no.

I was the voter for closing mainly because with no definite answer it seemed to be opinion based and so not exact - which I agree is debatable. But in general with no answer I could not see how this question was of use. With an answer it it should stay.

Note closed questions will be found on Google search so will still be visible - it requires deletion to remove them.

I would note that this is an easy question to deal with here as the state is only affected by one day. Other old questions are more problematic as the correct answer changes many times over time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I really only even looked into it because of the close vote. If it hadn't happened, the question could have slept for eternity & I guess many eventually do. I was happy I got off my fat one & found an answer. I'm still not really sure I had a true question above, but just to discuss it & how things like this fade over time, I guess.

Comment: So the close vote had its (by SE definition) intended result - it got an improved answer

Comment: I guess, yes. Happy SE users all round ;)